# python pandas: remove duplicates row in each seperate section

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
A B
a T
b T
c F
d F
e F
f T
g T
```

I want to keep the last event of each section

Should turn into this:

```
A B
b T
e F    
g T
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
df[df.B.ne(df.B.shift(-1))]
```

---

```
   A  B
1  b  T
4  e  F
6  g  T
```

**Details**- using [`df.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and `periods= -1` will shift the column one above example below:

```
print(df.B.shift(-1)) 

0      T
1      F
2      F
3      F
4      T
5      T
6    NaN
```

using the above output, we do a comparison with the present row:

```
df.B.ne(df.B.shift(-1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
```

now we have a boolean output to which we can directly call the dataframe which will select all the `True` index.